# Keycloak integration with Azure AD

Tags: azure, keycloak, saml

I am having problems integrating Keycloak and Azure AD for authenticating access to a Web App.

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.alphabold.com/azure-ad-configuration/), however at the stage of adding the Application ID URI we get this error:

[image: App ID Error]

Could someone explain what the issue might be? Is the verified domain of the Azure Organization, or Keycloak?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue is due to this [MS change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#appid-uri-in-single-tenant-applications-will-require-use-of-default-scheme-or-verified-domains).

Fix is to add a 'Custom Domain', https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/07/28/zero_to_hero_pt5.html.